How to make an EJB export a transitive dependency JAR to dependent EARs
I have one EAR, say first-ear.ear, which has an EJB in it, say first-ejb.jar, so its application.xml would be something like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
         version="6">
  <display-name>First App</display-name>
  <module>
      <ejb>first-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>

Then I have another EAR, say second-ear.ear, which declares a dependency on the EJB module of the first one. So, in JBoss EAP I would have the following jboss-deployment-structure.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="deployment.first-ear.ear.first-ejb.jar" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Now, what I need to do is to split first-ejb.jar into two pieces:

one still called first-ejb.jar, to maintain the same EJB name, which however is a stripped-down version of the original first-ejb.jar
another called first-common.jar, which contains some of the classes which were originally in first-ejb.jar

Of course, first-common.jar is put into the first-ear.ear. It might even be a plain JAR, not an EJB itself, unless strictly needed.
The problem I see now is that, when I run second-ear.ear, the deployment fails because some class in first-ejb.jar now needs classes in first-common.jar and these classes seems not to be "exported" to the second-ear.ear deployment module (so I hit NoClassDefFoundError/ClassNotFoundException errors when trying to deploy second-ear.ear).
What is the right way to solve this problem, possibly without requiring me to change the deployment descriptor in second-ear.ear? Is there a way to tell the first EAR to also transitively (and silently) export first-common.jar when exporting first-ejb.jar into dependent modules?
